# How do I get the old lock screen in 14.04?

Tags: unity, 14.04, lock-screen

Is it possible to revert to the old (12.04-13.xx) lock screen from the current Unity lock screen in Ubuntu? If so, how can I do it from the terminal? I have to script this change across 200+ computers, so a non-GUI method is highly preferred.

The new lock screen is buggy and a pain to use in multi-user environments:

- The Unity lock screen isn't playing well with LDAP. Often it gives an invalid password error, and the user has to use *Switch Accounts* action (from the gear menu) to get to LightDM and then log in, which always works fine. A known [bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/unity/+bug/1314095), apparently.
- I can't find any quick way to use the *Switch Accounts* action. In the LightDM version, there would be a *Switch Accounts* button which was only a couple of <kbd>Tab</kbd> presses away. If some user leaves his PC without logging off, everytime the screen locks, that user's lock screen is shown, forcing other users to use the *Switch Accounts* action from the gear menu (for which keyboard shortcuts are not readily apparent) to unlock their sessions.

A couple of iterations more, and the Unity lock screen might start working fine, but for now, any scriptable way to get back to the old way is highly appreciated. I am aware of [the CCSM way](http://linuxg.net/how-to-get-the-old-ubuntu-lockscreen-on-your-ubuntu-14-04-trusty-tahr/), and it will be a last-resort action.

Let me stress: the bugs are irrelevant to me. Reporting and solving them can be done in good time, after I have got the old one back.

Comment: http://linuxg.net/how-to-get-the-old-ubuntu-lockscreen-on-your-ubuntu-14-04-trusty-tahr/

Comment: @Tim I've seen that method, but how do I configure CCSM to use `lightdm` from the terminal? And I recall seeing a more recent post elsewhere which said that this method no longer worked.

Comment: My mistake, sorry... Just checked. Can I ask why you need to do this?

Comment: @Tim I have updated the question.